# Algolia vue auto select facets

Tags: vue.js, search, vue-component, full-text-search, algolia

I am developing an algolia search solution for an ecommerce app with around ~30000 products.

I tried to use the `<ais-configure/>` component to filter my results before showing them on the page, as I am working with different pages for each category of products and some facet filters also need to be applied if a user was to click on a promotion which would lead to this search result in the code below.

### The problem is:

Whenever I use the filters in `<ais-configure/>` the same filters are not picked up by my `<ais-refinement-list/>` component which should have the refined facets highlighted.

> The below code is not working but descriptive enough for the problem.

## Template

```js
<ais-instant-search :search-client.camel="searchClient" index-name="products">
    <ais-configure
      :filters.camel="searchParameters.filters"
      :facet-filters.camel="searchParameters.facetFilters"
    />

    <ais-infinite-hits>

      <div
        slot="loadMore"
        slot-scope="{ isLastPage, refineNext }"
        class="w-full my-12 px-6 text-sm-black-primary"
      >
        <button
          class="
            w-full
            h-20
            border-4
            rounded-md
            border-sm-black-primary
            font-semibold
            text-xl
            mb-24
          "
          :disabled="isLastPage"
          @click="refineNext"
        >
          See more
        </button>
      </div>
    </ais-infinite-hits>

    <products-filter-section>
      <div v-for="(filterType, id) in filterTypes" :key="id">
        <ais-refinement-list :attribute="filterType" searchable show-more>
          <template
            slot-scope="{
              items,
              isShowingMore,
              isFromSearch,
              canToggleShowMore,
              refine,
              createURL,
              toggleShowMore,
              searchForItems,
            }"
          >
            <div>
              <UtilsFancyTitle
                :text="filterType"
                text-size="text-lg"
                class="ml-4 my-4"
              />
              <input
                class="bg-white"
                @input="searchForItems($event.currentTarget.value)"
              />
              <ul class="flex flex-wrap">
                <li v-if="isFromSearch && !items.length">No results ...</li>
                <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.value" class="my-4 mr-4">
                  <a
                    :href="createURL(item)"
                    :class="
                      item.isRefined
                        ? 'font-semibold bg-sm-yellow-primary border-sm-yellow-primary '
                        : 'font-medium'
                    "
                    class="
                      border-4 border-sm-black-primary
                      py-1.5
                      px-2
                      rounded-md
                      text-sm
                    "
                    @click.prevent="refine(item.value)"
                  >
                    <ais-highlight attribute="item" :hit="item" />
                    ( {{ item.count.toLocaleString() }} )
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                <div class="w-1/4 h-1 bg-sm-black-primary rounded-md"></div>
                <button
                  class="w-2/4 font-semibold my-6"
                  :disabled="!canToggleShowMore"
                  @click="toggleShowMore"
                >
                  {{ !isShowingMore ? 'Show more' : 'Hide' }}
                </button>
                <div class="w-1/4 h-1 bg-sm-black-primary rounded-md"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </ais-refinement-list>
      </div>
    </products-filter-section>
  </ais-instant-search>
```

## Script

```js
import {
  AisInstantSearch,
  AisRefinementList,
  AisInfiniteHits,
  AisConfigure,
} from 'vue-instantsearch'
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    AisInstantSearch,
    AisRefinementList,
    AisInfiniteHits,
    AisConfigure,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        '[API-ENDPOINT]',
        '[API-KEY]'
      ),
      filterTypes: [
        'type',
        'color',
      ],
      searchParameters: {
        filters: `category:${this.$route.path.split('/').pop()}`,
        facetFilters: `type:someProductType`,
      },
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.css@7.4.5/themes/reset-min.css',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

### Is there any working solution for this?

The facets should be auto selected and in their refined state (for example: having their isRefined property set to rue) whenever the algolia query loads and the page renders.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been posted a while ago, so you might already have found an answer, but I'll post mine anyway since I landed here after having the same issue.

In my case, at least, there were 2 problems:

1. I hadn't configured the "Attributes for faceting". This is explained [in the docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/how-to/declaring-attributes-for-faceting/) and can be done easily via the admin or via API.
2. I was specifying the facets incorrectly in code. In your example above I *think* you should have:

```js
      searchParameters: {
        facetFilters: [[`type:someProductType`]],
      },
```

Note that now `facetFilters` is an array within an array.
What helps me when I'm unsure I open the admin UI of Algolia, select a search and apply whichever filter I want and then check the raw output. An example from my admin ui:

[image]

This gives me an idea of the correct shapes InstantSearch needs.